# .htaccess RewriteRule with one id parameter and no title parameter

Tags: php, database, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters

How should I write in htaccess file to rewrite this

`https://www.example.com/folder/subfolder/product.php?id=1`

where "id = 1" is the product_id in the database

as
`https://www.example.com/product/name-of-the-product/`

where "name-of-the-product" is the name of the product in the database

My try:

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewriterule ^product/(.+)\./ folder/subfolder/product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Instead of the id in the new url I need the name of the product, how can I do that???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `^product/(.+)\./` would demand the product name ends with `./` - I doubt that’s actually what you want.

Comment: (And of course you will need to change your application logic to go look up the product in the database via the name instead of the id then.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule with ID-any-product-name, ex. https://www.example.com/product/1-any-product-name

RewriteRule ^product/(\d+)-(.*)$ folder/subfolder/product.php?id=$1 [L]